# running systemd-run with some bpf-firewall rules as regular user does not work

Tags: systemd, ip-address

I'm trying to run a program with restricted networking via systemd-run

as root

**systemd-run  -p IPAddressAllow=192.168.253.1 -p IPAddressDeny=any** PROGRAM works nicely

but as regular user none of the IP setting takes effect.

I've tried to set **Delegate=bpf-firewall** with no success. I really don't know if i need to delegate or not, just shooting blind here.

Thanks.